# Autofill value in subform based on value in parent form

Tags: ms-access, autofill

I am creating a subform (in datasheet view) based on a query (qryClientEmployment) to display employment history for the client whose information is stored in the parent form (frmClientInformation).  frmClientInformation is based on another query (qryClientInformation).

I have a filter on qryClientEmployment to select records based on the client ID field displayed on the parent form (frmClientInformation).

I WANT to be able to add new employment records to the subform and have access autofill the client ID based on the ClientID field on the parent form.

I have tried, without luck, setting the default value on the Client ID field on the table (which stores Client Employment history) equal to form!frmClientInformation!txtID.

I’m new to Access and am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

When you are new to Access, it is nearly always best to use the wizard to create controls. In this case, it would have offered you the option of adding Link Child Fields and Link Master Fields, and these are what you need. You can edit these properties for the subform control, but you must be careful to select the control, not the form contained. Link child fields will be completed with data from the parent form master field, a misleading name, because the link master field can be a control. You can have multiple link child and master fields separated by semi-colons.

Do yourself a favour and change from datasheet to continuous form, you will have much more control.